# How to deploy application into google app engine

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I created one application in eclipse.I want to deploy my application into google app engine.How to deploy my application into google app engine.

Answer (score 3):

You have the App Engine Eclipse Plugin, right?

You need to set your application id in appengine-web.xml first, and then press the deploy button (or from the context menu: Google > Deploy to App Engine). It will ask for your account id and password.

Everything happens right in Eclipse.